# Specify --basetemp while keeping the per-session folder behavior

Tags: python-2.7, testing, pytest

Using pytest, is there a way to keep the auto-folder behavior when specifying a base folder?

I'd like to move the pytest folders from %TEMP% to a specific root, but when using the --basetemp argument, pytest doesn't create one folder per session like before.

Without --basetemp:

```
%TEMP%\pytest-90
           \test1()
           \test2()
           \test3()
%TEMP%\pytest-91
           \test1()
           \test2()
           \test3()
%TEMP%\pytest-92
           \test1()
           \test2()
           \test3()
```

With --basetemp=D:\Tests

```
D:\Tests
       \test1()
       \test2()
       \test3()
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
D:\Tests\pytest-90
           \test1()
           \test2()
           \test3()
D:\Tests\pytest-91
           \test1()
           \test2()
           \test3()
D:\Tests\pytest-92
           \test1()
           \test2()
           \test3()
```

Workarounds that work:

- I can create the folders myself when launching py.test from a python
  file and set that as the basetemp.
- Implement my own fixture that
  pulls tmpdir, and calculate it from there.
- Change my temp path environment variable

But i'm looking for a builtin way? Can we keep the auto-folder behavior AND specify a new basetemp at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: The accepted answer is from 2014, since then the function getbasetemp() changed:

```
def getbasetemp(self) -> Path:
    """Return base temporary directory."""
    if self._basetemp is not None:
        return self._basetemp

    if self._given_basetemp is not None:
        basetemp = self._given_basetemp
        ensure_reset_dir(basetemp)
        basetemp = basetemp.resolve()
    else:
        from_env = os.environ.get("PYTEST_DEBUG_TEMPROOT")
        temproot = Path(from_env or tempfile.gettempdir()).resolve()
        user = get_user() or "unknown"
        # use a sub-directory in the temproot to speed-up
        # make_numbered_dir() call
        rootdir = temproot.joinpath(f"pytest-of-{user}")
        rootdir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
        basetemp = make_numbered_dir_with_cleanup(
            prefix="pytest-", root=rootdir, keep=3, lock_timeout=LOCK_TIMEOUT
        )
    assert basetemp is not None, basetemp
    self._basetemp = t = basetemp
    self._trace("new basetemp", t)
    return t
```

According to that code, you could set the environment variable PYTEST_DEBUG_TEMPROOT. Then, the folders would be called like this:

> PYTEST_DEBUG_TEMPROOT/pytest-of-USER/pytest-NUMBER/popen-gwX/....

Directories such as "popen-gwX" only exist in case of using pytest-xdist

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code that manages the basetemp directory, that doesn't seem possible currently:

```
def getbasetemp(self):
    """ return base temporary directory. """
    try:
        return self._basetemp
    except AttributeError:
        basetemp = self.config.option.basetemp
        if basetemp:
            basetemp = py.path.local(basetemp)
            if basetemp.check():
                basetemp.remove()
            basetemp.mkdir()
        else:
            basetemp = py.path.local.make_numbered_dir(prefix='pytest-')
        self._basetemp = t = basetemp.realpath()
        self.trace("new basetemp", t)
        return t
```

I recommend creating an issue at the [tracker](https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/pytest/issues) to see what others have to say.

Comment: Thanks :) https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/pytest/issue/617/iterative-tmpdir-folders-lost-when-using

Answer (score 1):

I set TEMP=logs and pytest retains the rotating numbered dir model under the new folder. This is a product of py.path.local API. On the other hand, basetemp, is not intended for the purpose you request, its primarily a good tool for a fixed log dir perhaps best used in CICD.